# Tkinter GUI development: Centering Buttons

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a problem centering buttons on a window horizontally with the Python 3 tkinter module. Using `padx=some_value` or `pady=some_value` leaves it looking ugly, and gridding is not what I'm looking for.

My hope is that I can have two buttons centered and side-by-side.

Here's what I got so far:

```
import tkinter

gui = tkinter.Tk()
gui.title('TicTacToe')
gui.geometry('700x700')

singlePlayerBut = tkinter.Button(gui, text='Single Player', command=0)
singlePlayerBut.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT, padx=50, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)
multiPlayerBut = tkinter.Button(gui, text='Multi Player', command=0)
multiPlayerBut.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, padx=50, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)

gui.mainloop()
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You can nest the buttons in a new `Frame` and center that. Create the `Frame` and us it as the parent argument instead of `gui`.

Comment: Why against grid? It is the perfect method for aligning multiple widgets systematically, and in this case to get what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can use `grid` instead:

```
import tkinter

gui = tkinter.Tk()
gui.title('TicTacToe')
gui.geometry('700x700')

gui.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
gui.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
gui.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)

singlePlayerBut = tkinter.Button(gui, text='Single Player', command=0)
singlePlayerBut.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="e")
multiPlayerBut = tkinter.Button(gui, text='Multi Player', command=0)
multiPlayerBut.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="w")

gui.mainloop()
```

Or if you don't care about anything else and just want those two buttons at center, use `place`.

```
singlePlayerBut.place(relx=0.4,rely=0.5)
multiPlayerBut.place(relx=0.51,rely=0.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to implement what I suggested in a comment:

```
import tkinter

gui = tkinter.Tk()
gui.title('TicTacToe')
gui.geometry('700x700')

button_frame = tkinter.Frame(gui)  # Frame to hold (and group) buttons.
singlePlayerBut = tkinter.Button(button_frame, text='Single Player', command=0)
singlePlayerBut.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT, padx=50, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)
multiPlayerBut = tkinter.Button(button_frame, text='Multi Player', command=0)
multiPlayerBut.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, padx=50, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)
button_frame.pack()  # Default side is tkinter.TOP

gui.mainloop()
```